# React enzyme react router test case warning: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, enzyme, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom in my react app. App works fine in browser without any error or warning,
but when I am writing tests, I am getting a warning 'React.createElement: type is ....'

Here is my test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/nav-bar';
import {configure, mount, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import {expect} from 'chai';
import App from "./App";
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        pathname: '/another-route',
        search: '',
        hash: '',
        state: null,
        key: '5nvxpbdafa',
    }),
}));

describe("Movie Library Testing", () => {
    it('renders react app', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <App/>
        );
        expect(wrapper.find(NavBar)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
    });

    it('renders an `.navbar-brand', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <MemoryRouter>
                <NavBar user={null}/>
            </MemoryRouter>
        );
        expect(wrapper.find('.navbar-brand')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
    });
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your componen
t from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    
    Check your code at nav-bar.tsx:41.
        in NavBar (at App.test.tsx:31)
        in Router (created by MemoryRouter)
        in MemoryRouter (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent
```

The NavBar.tsx has following code at given Line:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
<NavLink className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</NavLink>

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: There is no export statement in your code. So NavBar is undefined in your test code. Can you post your NavBar.tsx fully

Comment: @VigneshMurugan if you check, it is going to file 'nav-bar.tsx'

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
import {NavBar} from './components';
```

to

```
import NavBar from './components';
```

Comment: I have made sure of this. But still no luck. Also updated the question.

Comment: @Sanky in your test file, you're also testing the app. and in app, you probably forgot to change `import {NavBar}` to `import NavBar` also. also after updating the code, please update the error stack.

Comment: @Sanky, post your nav-bar.tsx code for accurate analysis. Here is a possible nav-bar.tsx that you may have:

`import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function NavBar () {
  return (
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</NavLink>
  )
}`

Comment: @ParikshithKedilayaM Thanks. I found the problem. It was the mock 'react-router-dom' causing the proble,